# react route - How to use history.push to switch components ? Only URL changes

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom, history

I have a fucntion that I want it to replace the components between `Header` and `Footer` components.
Where/How should I use the `defaultRouter` function with the `history.push`. I see **only the URL is changed**. 
The the `Header` component is updating the `pageIndex`. 
I tried to change `defaultRouter` to a `useCallback` function but that didn't worked at all.

What i the order of theses functions?
App.js

```js
function App() {
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [itemsAmount, setItemsAmount] = useState('');
  const [pageIndex, setPageIndex] = useState();

  const history = createBrowserHistory();

  // let history = useHistory();

  const defaultRouter = useMemo(() => {
    console.log(pageIndex);
    switch (pageIndex) {
      case 1:
        history.push({ pathname: '/search', state: searchResults });
        break;
      case 2:
        history.push('/cart');
        break;
      default:
        history.push('/');
        break;
    }
  }, [pageIndex]);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Header
        settingResults={setSearchResults}
        itemsCartAmount={itemsAmount}
        setPageIndex={setPageIndex}
      />
       {defaultRouter}
       <Footer />
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/'>
            <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path='/search'>
            <Search/>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/cart'>
            <Cart />
          </Route>
          <Route component={PageNotFound} />;
        </Switch>
      </Router>
     
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Edit

I just removed `BrowserRouter` from Index.js, the same problem.

Index.js

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This way above the `pageIndex` is updating but `history.push` don't switch the components.

Comment: Can you tell use why you are using 2 Routers in your Application ?

Comment: Hi @kumarmo2 , it was adiviced to me in a previous question of mine, I just removed the `  <BrowserRouter>` in `Index.js`. The same problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is happening here is that `history` object is getting created everytime when the `pageIndex` is being updated.  Ideally it should be created just once manually.

You can find the working solution here [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-pond-gcqsg?file=/src/App.js).

I have updated

- the logic for creating history object
- removed `Router` from App
- used `useHistory` to get the history object in the component.
- also wrote the effect to push changes when `pageIndex` is updated.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checkig it right now. I have a question -  `useEffect` will render the `Home` component one more time after the first render, can I prevent that ?

Comment: I am not sure why you are using `pageIndex` but I would actually get rid of `pageIndex`. On click of buttons, i would directly do `history.push` instead of setting the state. and as soon as we get rid of `pageIndex`, effect will also be gone

Comment: In my Index.js I wrapped my App with `BrowserRouter` as you did, but only the URL changes.

Comment: So how will I use `history.push` inside the `Header` when all the routs are in APP.js   ? without `pageIndex`.

Comment: if you notice, I have created `history` object outside any component. This makes sure the history object is created just once. you were creating history object inside the `App` that means any time the state is updated, a new history object is created

Comment: don't push insdie the header, pass a callback as prop from App and do it inside App. 

or you can retrieve history using `useHistory` inside Header and push it as well. Upto you how you want to design your components

Answer (score 1):

**update**

please have a look at this, I tried to replicate your issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-swartz-jxc5p?file=/src/App.js

You have used Router twice, one inside `App.js` as `<Router>` and other inside `index.js` as `<BrowserRouter>`.
What you need to do is; only use  inside App.js and make sure it is imported as:

`import {Router} from 'react-router-dom';`

as Router accepts history prop, not the BrowserRouter, and also remove `BrowserRouter` from `index.js`.

For safer side, use `useHistory()` hook for history value.

This will fix your issue.

[image: Clicking on Button 1]

[image: Clicking on button 2]

Comment: I Removed `BrowserRouter` from index.js, still only the URL changes to `/search`

Comment: @ExtraSun please check updated answer, I have attached a link to codesandbox. I tried to replicate your issue.

Comment: Using `let history = useHistory()` -  ` return ( <div className='App' <Router history={history}>`  makes error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.
`  Your code in *https://codesandbox.io* only changes the URL not the component.

Comment: I checked it and it was switching the components as well. Anyhow, can you please update your code with all the `import` statements, there might be an issue there.

Comment: Strange, because I see only "Sample" when clicking the buttons, not `<h1> Cart </h1>;`

Comment: I can see the headings being changed, I wish I could attach some sort of video or images here. It's still working.

Comment: Thank you for your effort to help anyway.

Comment: You are welcome. I have attached the images in answer to show the results.

Comment: Maybe it's a different *codesandbox.io*  link than you put in your answer.